# How do you NOT focus on any input text fields in a form after a page loads?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input, focus

I have a form loaded in a simplemodal overlay, but it focuses on the first input field. Is there anyway to have the form not focus (meaning the field is selected and the user is able to type into it right away without having to click it) on any text input field after a form loads?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in jquery:

when you add the form do this:

```
$('input').each(function(){ $(this).blur(); });
```

Comment: No need for the .each() there.

Answer (score 7):

```
$(function () {
    $('input').blur();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an option in the parameters for the simple modal. Just do focus:false. http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/#example-5

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('form input').blur();
});
```